# NSFetchedResultsController fill sections with subentity array

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `fetchRequest` that returns some `objects`. The `object.name` is the section title. I would like `object.subObjects` to form the corresponding rows for each `section` so that I can use `indexPath` rather than referring to `fetchedObjects`. Is there some way to do this?